# show result from percentage

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Hello I have I field in my table called percentage but what I looking to do is only show a result based on percentage ie if I set 10 it would only show the result 10% of the time.

here is my database which is Joomla database code in mysql

```
        // Select the required fields from the table.
        $query->select(
            'a.id, a.title, a.simulator, a.generation, a.quality, a.quantity, a.percentage, a.attribute, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.catid' .
            ', a.state, a.access, a.created, a.created_by, a.version, a.ordering'
        );

        $query->from('#__evolutionary_texture AS a');

        // Join over the users for the checked out user.
        $query->select('uc.name AS editor')
            ->join('LEFT', '#__users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out');

        // Join over the asset groups.
        $query->select('ag.title AS access_level')
            ->join('LEFT', '#__viewlevels AS ag ON ag.id = a.access');

        // Join over the species.
        $query->select('category.title AS category_title')
            ->join('LEFT', '#__categories AS category ON category.id = a.catid');

        $query->select('parent.title AS parent_title')
            ->join('left', '#__categories AS parent ON parent.id=category.parent_id');

        // Join over the section.
        //$query->select('section.title AS section_title')
        //  ->join('LEFT', '#__categories AS section ON section.id = a.catid');

        // Join over the users for the author.
        $query->select('ua.name AS author_name')
            ->join('LEFT', '#__users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by');

        $query->where('parent.title = ' . $db->quote($species));
        //echo "section = $section";
        $query->where('category.title = ' . $db->quote($section));

        // check where generation.
        $query->where('a.generation = ' . $db->quote($generation));

        // check where simulator.
        $query->where('a.simulator = ' . $db->quote($simulator));

        // Debug the query
        //var_dump($db->replacePrefix( (string) $query ) );

        // Set the query and load the result.
        $db->setQuery($query);
```

as what I trying to do is only show texture based on the percentage as this data is imported into a game called second life

my percentage field right now goes from 0 - 100

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: well I looking at counting the quality based on percentage on show for example common or rare etc and show the result where I can then use the array to generate the data for the result in the query

Comment: I would get the result list and then use a php randomization function weighted by percent to select one.

Comment: try with adding new condition as in my answer `$query->where('a.percentage >= ' . $random_no[$times] );` | if not work then write with problem i'll try to solve.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your code/problem, I can suggest following.

1. you need to store a variable `random_no` and `times` somewhere, in SESSION, DATABSE or APPLIATION level var
2. The value of `random_no` will be `=array() of 100 int values from 1 to 100 randomly`// example `=array(23,15,67,98, ...., 5); // all 1-100 numbers once only`
3. value of `times` will be `0` initially and will increase by `1` after each query. When value reach to `99` then next it will be `0` and recalculate the value of `random_no`. //code at where are querying database
4. Now run your query with condition: `a.percentage >= $random_no[$times]`

---

creating **$randome_no** array:

```
 $random_no=array();
 for($i=1;$i<=100;i++){
     $random_no[]=$i;
 }
 shuffle($random_no);
```

[PHP shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

**Above method will select records `percentage` times randomly**